# gcc incorrectly reusing registers in inline asm

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, inline-assembly, cpu-registers

I've implemented a simple delay loop macro in a C program for the Cortex-M4:

```
#define DELAY_CYCLES (F_CPU / 3000000) //F_CPU is 72000000
#define delayUS(n) __asm__ volatile( \
    "1: subs %0, #1       \n" \
    "bne 1b               \n" \
    : /* no outputs */ \
    : "r" (n * DELAY_CYCLES) /* input */ \
    : "0" /* clobbers */ \
)
```

This delays for `n` microseconds (assuming interrupts are disabled). Mostly, it works fine. However, I've found that it doesn't work correctly in a function that uses it twice:

```
static void test(uint8_t num) {
    digitalWrite(12, 1);
    delayUS(10);
    digitalWrite(13, 1);
    delayUS(10);
    digitalWrite(12, 0);
    digitalWrite(13, 0);
}
```

(This was a function that actually uses `num`, but got stripped down to this while debugging this issue. It also gets inlined into `main`, hence the labels in the disassembly.)

What happens here is the second call to `delayUS()` never completes. Examining the generated assembly shows the problem:

```
 528:   2701        movs    r7, #1
 52a:   6037        str r7, [r6, #0]    ;digitalWrite(12, 1)
 52c:   23f0        movs    r3, #240    ;delayUS(10); 10 * DELAY_CYCLES = 240
 52e:   3b01        subs    r3, #1
 530:   d1fd        bne.n   52e <main+0x4a>

 532:   4c0d        ldr r4, [pc, #52]
 534:   6027        str r7, [r4, #0]    ;digitalWrite(13, 1)

 536:   3b01        subs    r3, #1      ;delayUS(10), but r3 is still 0
 538:   d1fd        bne.n   536 <main+0x52>

 53a:   2300        movs    r3, #0
 53c:   6033        str r3, [r6, #0]    ;digitalWrite(12, 0)
```

For some reason, gcc doesn't re-initialize `r3` before using it in the second delay loop, so instead of delaying for 240 iterations (10µs), it delays for 2^32 (about 3 minutes).

With this variation, the issue disappears:

```
__attribute__((used)) static int dummy;
#define delayUS(n) __asm__ volatile( \
    "1: subs %0, #1       \n" \
    "bne 1b               \n" \
    : "=r" (dummy) /* no outputs */ \
    : "0" (n * DELAY_CYCLES) /* input */ \
    : "0" /* clobbers */ \
)
```

That generates more correct code:

```
 528:   2701        movs    r7, #1
 52a:   23f0        movs    r3, #240    ;r3 = 10 * DELAY_CYCLES
 52c:   6037        str r7, [r6, #0]    ;digitalWrite(12, 1)
 52e:   461a        mov r2, r3          ;r2 = r3

 530:   3a01        subs    r2, #1      ;delayUS(r2)
 532:   d1fd        bne.n   530 <main+0x4c>

 534:   4c0d        ldr r4, [pc, #52]
 536:   6027        str r7, [r4, #0]    ;digitalWrite(13, 1)

 538:   3b01        subs    r3, #1      ;delayUS(r3)
 53a:   d1fd        bne.n   538 <main+0x54>

 53c:   4a0c        ldr r2, [pc, #48]
 53e:   6013        str r3, [r2, #0]    ;digitalWrite(12, 0)
```

Here, it's correctly realized that the delay loop clobbers its input register, and so doesn't re-use `r3` without initializing it (it uses `r2` for one of the loops instead.)

So, why does gcc not recognize that the former version also clobbers its input, when it's listed in the clobber list?

Comment: I'm going to guess and say 'macros'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the 'clobbers' list is a list of register names, or the special strings "cc" and "memory".  Since there is no register called "0", having this in the clobbers list is meaningless.  Unfortuately gcc does not give you a warning about this.  Instead, as the gcc docs note:

> **Warning**: Do not modify the contents of input-only operands (except for inputs tied to outputs). The compiler assumes that on exit from the asm statement these operands contain the same values as they had before executing the statement. It is not possible to use clobbers to inform the compiler that the values in these inputs are changing. One common work-around is to tie the changing input variable to an output variable that never gets used.

This workaround is what your second example does, and is why it works.  For correctness, you should probably also add "cc" to the clobbers list (as you modify the flags), and you might as well remove the "0", because it is meaningless.

Comment: A "0" clobber isn't "totally" meaningless. Just "almost entirely" meaningless. It allows you to refer to registers by number instead of by name. On i386: `asm ("" : : "a" (0) : "0");` gives "impossible constraints" since I am both using and clobbering the same register (using "1" compiles without error). However, I wouldn't depend upon the ordering of registers. There are comments in gcc's code that suggest the list of registers can get re-ordered during a compilation. So using "0" does have an effect. But since you presumably don't want to clobber a random register, I'm with Chris: Remove it.

Comment: I see. I thought you could specify "0" (or "%0") to say that whatever register is %0 in the code will get clobbered.

Comment: Correction: I said the order of registers is random.  That's wrong.  The order of registers is fixed.  So "0" and "%0" still aren't related (except by accident).  But if you wanted to clobber eax, you can reference it by its index ("0") or by its name ("eax").  Note that the index order of registers may not be what you expect ("1" is NOT ebx).